# When The FP-injective cover of module is surjective

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Definition of cover of module is: 
Let $R$ be a ring and let $\mathcal{S}$ be any class of $R$-modules.
Then for any $R$-module $M$, the homomorphism $\beta:S\longrightarrow
M$ is called an $\mathcal{S}$-precover of $M$ if $S\in
\mathcal{S}$ and $\beta^{*}=Hom(F',\beta):Hom(S',S)\longrightarrow
Hom(S',M)$ is surjective for every $S'\in \mathcal{S}$. An
$\mathcal{S}$-precover $\beta:S\longrightarrow
M$ is called an $\mathcal{S}$-cover, if for every homomorphism  $f:S\longrightarrow S$
such that $\beta\circ f=\beta$, $f$ is an automorphism.

and the defintion of FP-injective module is :
A module $H$ is said to be FP-injective if
    $Ext^{1}_{R}(P,H)=0$ for each finitely presented module $P$.

The Question is 
let $M\longrightarrow E(M)$ be the injective envelope of $M.$
Consider the exact sequence $0\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow E(M)\longrightarrow
 E(M)/M\longrightarrow 0,$ we have $E(M)\longrightarrow
E(M)/M$ is an FP-injective precover of $E(M)/M$. Also, 
since $R$ is coherent, $E(M)/M$ has an FP-injective cover
$L\longrightarrow E(M)/M$. Then we obtain the following commutative diagram such that all rows are exact:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rinwh.png)

I did not understand how deduced this commutative diagram ? and what 
FP-injective cover is surjective ?

Answer (score 0):

it happens iff R Is FC ring by an accepted paper , "coherent ring and absolutely pure preprovers " https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319304138_Coherent_rings_and_absolutely_pure_covers

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE and thank you for your answer. Please add some key information on your post (instead of a link) to make it searchable for other users around here.